# Unity2D: How to make spawn object gradually go faster after the player collects 10 points?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, spawn

so I was wondering if there was a way to make a spawned object gradually moves/go faster after the player (you the user) collects 10 points. And faster when the player collects another 10 points and so on and so on?

This is my movement script attach to my objects that get spawned in:

```
public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
  {
   public static int movespeed = 20;
   public Vector3 userDirection = Vector3.right;

public void Update()
 {
    transform.Translate(userDirection * movespeed * Time.deltaTime); 
 }
}
```

This is my score script attach to my player

```
public int Score;
public Text ScoreText;

void Start ()
{
    Score = 0;
    SetScoreText ();
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ("Pick Up")) 
    {
        other.gameObject.SetActive (false);
        Score = Score + 1;
        SetScoreText ();
    }
}

void SetScoreText ()
{
    ScoreText.text = "Score: " + Score.ToString ();
}
```

And this is my generateEnemy script:

```
public GameOverManager gameOverManager = null;

[HideInInspector]
public float minBlobSpawnTime = 2;
[HideInInspector]
public float maxBlobSpawnTime = 5;
[HideInInspector]
public bool generateBlobs = true;
[HideInInspector]
public GameObject blobPrefab = null;
[HideInInspector]
public GameObject blobRoot = null;
[HideInInspector]
public float minimumYPosition = -0.425f;
[HideInInspector]
public float maximumYPosition = 0.35f;

[HideInInspector]
public float minDaggerSpawnTime = 2;
[HideInInspector]
public float maxDaggerSpawnTime = 5;
[HideInInspector]
public bool generateDaggers = true;
[HideInInspector]
public GameObject daggerPrefab = null;
[HideInInspector]
public GameObject daggerRoot;
[HideInInspector]
public float minimumXPosition = -11.5f;
[HideInInspector]
public float maximumXPosition = 11.5f;

public Camera camera = null;

// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{
    generateBlobs = ((generateBlobs) && (blobPrefab != null) && (blobRoot != null));
    generateDaggers = ((generateDaggers) && (daggerPrefab != null) && (daggerRoot != null));

    if (camera == null)
    {
        Debug.LogError("GenerateEnemy: camera is not set in the inspector. Please set and try again.");
        camera = Camera.main;
    }

    if (gameOverManager == null)
    {
        Debug.LogError("GenerateEnemy: gameOverManager not set in the inspector. Please set and try again.");
    }

    if (generateBlobs)
    {
        StartCoroutine(GenerateRandomEnemy(true, blobPrefab, blobRoot, minBlobSpawnTime, maxBlobSpawnTime));
    }

    if (generateDaggers)
    {
        StartCoroutine(GenerateRandomEnemy(false, daggerPrefab, daggerRoot, minDaggerSpawnTime, maxDaggerSpawnTime));
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{
    DestroyOffScreenEnemies();
}

// Spawn an enemy
IEnumerator GenerateRandomEnemy(bool generateOnYAxis, GameObject prefab, GameObject root, float minSpawnTime, float maxSpawnTime)
{
    if ((prefab != null) && (gameOverManager != null))
    {
        if (!gameOverManager.GameIsPaused())
        {
            GameObject newEnemy = (GameObject) Instantiate(prefab);
            newEnemy.transform.SetParent(root.transform, true);

            // set this in the prefab instead
            // newEnemy.transform.position = new Vector3(newEnemy.transform.parent.position.x, 0.5f, newEnemy.transform.parent.position.z);

            // or if you want the y position to be random you need to do something like this
            if (generateOnYAxis)
            {
                newEnemy.transform.position = new Vector3(newEnemy.transform.parent.position.x, Random.Range(minimumYPosition, maximumYPosition), newEnemy.transform.parent.position.z);
            }
            else
            {
                newEnemy.transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range(minimumXPosition, maximumXPosition), newEnemy.transform.parent.position.y, newEnemy.transform.parent.position.z);
            }
        }
    }
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(minSpawnTime, maxSpawnTime));

    StartCoroutine(GenerateRandomEnemy(generateOnYAxis, prefab, root, minSpawnTime, maxSpawnTime));
}

public void DestroyOffScreenEnemies()
{
    GameObject[] enemies = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("enemy");
    if ((enemies.Length > 0) && (camera != null))
    {
        for  (int i = (enemies.Length - 1); i >= 0; i--)
        {
            // just a precaution
            if ((enemies[i] != null) && ((camera.WorldToViewportPoint(enemies[i].transform.position).x > 1.03f) || 
                                         (enemies[i].transform.position.y < -6f)))
            {
                Destroy(enemies[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

(This script has an generateEnemyCustomEditor script that references it, to show in the inspector)

Thank you :)

Comment: FYI you can accept answers on SO. Most of your old questions needs some attention. See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) on how to do that. You can always comment on those answers if they did not work for you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, remove the `static` keyword from `public static int movespeed = 20;` and use `GameObject.Find("ObjectMovementIsAttachedTo").GetComponent<Movement>();` to get the script instance if you want to modify `movespeed` variable from another script.

> And faster when the player collects another 10 points and so on and so
>   on?

The solution is straight on. Use

```
if (Score % 10 == 0){
  //Increement by number (4) movespeed from Movement script
    movement.movespeed += 4;
}
```

to check if the `Score` is increased by 10 then increment `movespeed` by any value you want if that condition is `true`. It makes sense to put that in the `OnTriggerEnter2D` function after Score is incremented by `1`.

Your new `score` script:

```
public class score : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int Score;
    public Text ScoreText;

    private int moveSpeed;

    void Start()
    {
        Score = 0;
        SetScoreText();
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Pick Up"))
        {
            other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            Score = Score + 1;
            if (Score % 10 == 0)
            {
                //Increement by number (4) movespeed from Movement script
                moveSpeed += 4;
            }
            SetScoreText();
        }
    }

    public int getMoveSpeed()
    {
        return moveSpeed;
    }

    void SetScoreText()
    {
        ScoreText.text = "Score: " + Score.ToString();
    }
}
```

Since your `Movement` script will be instantiated, when you instantiate it, you send its reference to the Player script.

```
public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int movespeed = 20;
    public Vector3 userDirection = Vector3.right;

    score mySpeed;

    void Start()
    {
        //Send Movement instance to the score script
        GameObject scoreGameObject = GameObject.Find("GameObjectScoreIsAttachedTo");
        mySpeed = scoreGameObject.GetComponent<score>();
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(userDirection * mySpeed.getMoveSpeed() * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm on mobile now . I'll try it out once I get home 

Comment: Sorry I got an error when I play the game: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Movement.SetScoreText () (at Assets/Script/Movement.cs:41). I tried moving the score text into the [box](http://imgur.com/ESRGA3g) but it won't allow it!

Comment: I think it's because my object is a prefab

Comment: UH, yeah sorry I was going to try it out when I wasn't so busy with other things. I will definitely try it out

Comment: Hi, yeah sorry. I got this error:NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Movement.Start () (at Assets/Script/Movement.cs:14). With this line:   scoreGameObject.GetComponent<Score>().rereiveMovementInstance(this);

Comment: Thank you, I tried out your suggested, but like only sometimes some of the spawned prefabs went fast

Comment: no there is multiple spawning in, kinda like fruit ninja.

Comment: The main part of my answer is `if (Score % 10 == 0){
  //Increement by number (4) movespeed from Movement script
    movement.movespeed += 4;
} ` This is what you are looking for. You should be able to implement the rest by yourself. If you are still having problems, I suggest you follow a simple project [tutorial](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials) on Unity before going forward. You need to understand the basics before going further. Learn how to use `GameObject.Find` and `GetComponent` which are basic Unity stuff. I updated the code for last time. That should work.

Comment: Otherwise, follow the tutorials on the link I provided so that you will be able to implement that which is very simple. Try the new code.

Comment: not really because it's still not working properly its still doing the same thing. :(