# Unity2D: Increase spawn object movement when player collects every 10 points

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make my spawned objects (enemy prefabs) movement speed up every 10 points my player collects.
This is my movement script, attached to my enemy prefab (so that it can be spawned in my game and move):

```
public static int movespeed = 20;
public Vector3 userDirection = Vector3.right;

public void Update()
{
    transform.Translate(userDirection * movespeed * Time.deltaTime); 
 }
}
```

And this is my score script attached to my player:

```
public Text ScoreText;
public AudioClip Coinsound;
public Text Highscoretext;
public GameObject enemy;
Movement movement;

private int Score;
public int highScore = 0;


void Start () 
{
    Score = 0;
    SetScoreText ();
    if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey ("Highscore")) 
    {
        highScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Highscore");
    }
}
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ("Pick Up")) {
        other.gameObject.SetActive (false);
        Score = Score + 1;
        SetScoreText ();
        AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint (Coinsound, transform.position);

    }
}
```

As mentioned before I want to make my spawned enemy prefabs to move faster when my player collects every ten points. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the `%` symbol to do that. After adding 1 to `Score`, Check if there is a reminder when `Score` is divided by `10`. If there is no remainder, increment. Don't increment of there is a remainder.

```
if (Score % 10 == 0){
  //Increment movespeed variable  from Movement script
    Movement.movespeed += 4;
}
```

Put the code above in your `OnTriggerEnter2D` function.

For some reason, this looks very similar to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38907515/3785314) but the OP failed to get that answer working.

Comment: Thank you, I tried it out. it kinda works, you see I change the normal movement script, movespeed to 1 to see that once I collected 10 point the Movement.movespeed +=4; would increase which it does it's just that I notice the movement script is gradually increasing my spawn objects, which is not what I want. I want my object to keep it's original movement and goes faster when my player collects 10 points. Once again thank you for your reply

Comment: "I notice the movement script is gradually increasing my spawn objects, which is not what I want." I don't know what you mean by that. Can you explain more abut the problem?

Comment: Thank you. Would you mind if I send you my project?? Also when I reply/restart my game (in the same scene) the spawn objects are still going super fast rather than going back to the it's original speed. :) Thank you for your time

Comment: Does this happen in the code in your question or after you apply my solution?

Comment: Sorry it took me long to reply, I had some important stuff to do, I tried you thing again and this time it work. I just have one problem, I was wondering if you can help me to put a limit, so that the movement script doesn't increase all the time  and getting even faster and faster even if the player continue to collect more 10 point and on wards